# A question related to box topology ( unable to understand the contradiction)

Tags: general-topology

This question is from take home assignments and some examples preceed them.

Consider these 2 images:

[image]

[image]

> In the last line of 2nd image, I am unable to see what will be the contradiction?

Rest all analysis is clear to me.

Please help with it.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are fixed, and the inclusion $(a, b) \subseteq (-1/n, 1/n)$ is supposed to hold for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  What numbers are there that satisfy $-1/n < x < 1/n$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly:

If $x\in \Bbb R$ then $f(x)=(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}\in\Bbb R^{\omega}$ where $x_n=x$ for every $n.$ So for any $x$ we have $$x\in f^{-1}B\implies f(x)\in B\implies \forall n\in \Bbb N\,(  x=x_n\in (-1/n, 1/n) \,)\implies$$ $$\implies  x\in\cap_{n\in \Bbb N}(-1/n,1/n)=\{0\}.$$

So $f^{-1}B\subseteq \{0\}.$ And (obviously) $0\in f^{-1}B.$ So $f^{-1}B=\{0\},$ which is not open in $\Bbb R.$

Comment: The box topology on $\Bbb R^{\omega}$ is rather strong. It is not 1st-countable. It is unknown whether it is normal ($T_4$) or not.